# What's the shape of the upper half of a sphere called?

Tags: single-word-requests

The shape of a cap, a igloo, and that sort of things. What's that shape called?

Is there a common way to refer to it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'upper part'?  You could say the 'upper half' or the 'top' of the circle, the second leaving things quite vague.

Comment: @Merk Yeah, sorry, I meant upper half.

Comment: Inverted bowl? (pun intended)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Dome](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dome) is the word that comes to my mind

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dome)

> A dome is an element of architecture that resembles the hollow upper half of a sphere.

So although it is also a hemisphere, the dome is the top half of a sphere, which is what janoChen was looking for

Comment: Absolutely, 'dome' it is. But a dome can be less than half, it usually is.

Comment: I would say there are a lot of half sphere domes here: http://goo.gl/3tOrlJ

Answer (score 7):

Half a circle called a ***semi-circle*** (with or without a hyphen).

> **semicircle** *noun*
>   a half of a circle or of its circumference.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/semicircle)

Half a sphere (like an igloo) is a ***hemisphere*** (which I've not generally seen hyphenated).

> **hemisphere** *noun*
>   a half of a sphere.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hemisphere)

Note that *circle* is derived from Latin, so takes a Latin prefix for "half", whereas *sphere* is derived from Greek and takes the Greek prefix.

Comment: Not necessarily the upper half, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean sphere, not circle, in which case *"hemi-sphere"* is another very/mathematical formal alternative to dome.

Sometimes you need to use '*arch*' -- although arches are not sections of spheres but something slightly different...Google images is very useful if more clarification is needed.

Finally a *parabola* is another variation not having to do with spheres or circles specifically but still in the same family of concepts: curving to a point (in this case, at top or at bottom).